# Flag converted into close vote

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

After reaching 3000 reputation points, I've been alerted of the fact that I may vote to close posts with low level quality -- and other possible reasons.

Since that, every time I flag a post, the flag seems to be *converted* into a *vote to close*, with the respective reason -- the same used to flag.

After being able to *vote to close* posts, does one's flagging activity stops, being converted into *close votes*? If so, how come some people have so much reputation, and considerably high levels of flagging activity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you have 3,000 reputation you should be **voting** to close, not **flagging** to close. You have earned the privilege so you should use it. Flagging would be considered abuse of the system so, as you have noticed, if you attempt to flag it is automatically converted to a vote. So you can no longer flag for this reason.

There are other flags you can raise on posts (if they are appropriate) - such as spam, low quality (though you should be editing or down-voting here as your first action) so your flagging activity shouldn't stop.

However you should make sure you are raising the right flags. For example, don't use the "other" option to tell us that a post needs closing. Do so is an abuse of the flagging system.

Comment: @Rubens Also flagging isn't restricted to questions, you can also flag answers and comments. Tons of non answers around waiting for your flags (but please use your downvotes first), and even more obsolete or too chatty (or worse) comments...

Comment: i really don't understand than why there is option to close as dup or off topic

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of other types of flags that can be raised on a post, aside from "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" (the one that is automatically converted into a close vote when you have close vote privileges):

[image]

Comment: imo its better to remove that option for >3k rep

Comment: @NullPonyPointer: If I recall, that was left there so that 3k+ rep users can still alert moderators to issues after they've used their daily allotment of close votes.