# If I flag a question, then get close vote privileges, I should be allowed to vote to close it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, flags, vote-to-close

I've just passed the threshold for being able to vote to close on another SE site. Some of the questions I flagged prior to having this privilege are still in the review queue because not enough votes have been cast to close them yet (it's a much smaller site than SO).

It seems that once you *have* the close vote privilege, [any flags-to-close you make after that are converted to votes-to-close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173520/flag-converted-into-close-vote). However, it's not clear whether this is retroactive and applies to the still-open flags I raised *before* getting this privilege.

When I go to the close vote review queue, these questions are still visible in the queue. Then when I click on "close" to agree with the close vote it says "You already flagged this question for closure". Searching on meta reveals that this (IMO **very confusing**) wording is because once you have privileges [close votes and flag-for-closures are counted the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193147/251229).

However, it's still not clear whether the **old** flags are converted to close votes. This is quite confusing.

**So here's my suggestion.**

- If the flag that I cast when I did not have privileges to vote to close has *not* been retroactively converted to a close vote (which seems more likely) then I should be allowed to cast a close vote.
- If my previous flag *does* now count as a vote, I think this should be worded more clearly: *You already voted to close this question* (as opposed to *You already flagged this question for closure*) and/or make it not appear in my close vote queue to begin with (since I've already voted and it won't let me vote again).

Comment: It shouldn't auto-convert because decisions when I had 500 rep might be different than when I have 3K, but a manual convert might be nice.

Comment: I agree with your argument, but I think if that's the case you should be allowed to vote on it. Because now you **do** have 3K (actually the threshold is 500 on the site in question but to follow your example I'll stick with your numbers) you are making your 3K-decision that you still want to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now live - see [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193146/should-flagging-a-question-for-closure-prevent-close-voting/237619#237619).